# Unable to set proper resolution on ultrawide Huawei Mateview GT 34 ( Using integrated intel GPU )

Tags: 22.04, multiple-monitors, xorg, display-resolution, wayland

I've just recently ditched Windows and installed Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS on my PC but unfortunatelly i can't seem to be able to set the resolution i want ( 3440x1440 )

This is what i'm rocking:

CPU: 11th Gen Intel® Core™ i5-1135G7 @ 2.40GHz × 8

GPU: Intel Corporation TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics]

Monitor: HUAWEI MateView GT 34'' Ultrawide Curved Gaming Monitor, 165Hz, 21:9 WQHD

I've tried to do the following things ( i've tried things both with X11 and with Wayland ) :

First with X11:

```
robert@robert-Vostro-3400:~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 1447, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 174mm
   1920x1080     59.93*+  47.99  
   1680x1050     59.93  
   1400x1050     59.93  
   1600x900      59.93  
   1280x1024     59.93  
   1400x900      59.93  
   1280x960      59.93  
   1440x810      59.93  
   1368x768      59.93  
   1280x800      59.93  
   1280x720      59.93  
   1024x768      59.93  
   960x720       59.93  
   928x696       59.93  
   896x672       59.93  
   1024x576      59.93  
   960x600       59.93  
   960x540       59.93  
   800x600       59.93  
   840x525       59.93  
   864x486       59.93  
   700x525       59.93  
   800x450       59.93  
   640x512       59.93  
   700x450       59.93  
   640x480       59.93  
   720x405       59.93  
   684x384       59.93  
   640x360       59.93  
   512x384       59.93  
   512x288       59.93  
   480x270       59.93  
   400x300       59.93  
   432x243       59.93  
   320x240       59.93  
   360x202       59.93  
   320x180       59.93  
HDMI-1 connected 1920x1080+0+367 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 797mm x 334mm
   1920x1080     60.00*   60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08
```

And i tried to do the following steps:

```
robert@robert-Vostro-3400:~$ cvt 3440 1440 60 
# 3440x1440 59.94 Hz (CVT) hsync: 89.48 kHz; pclk: 419.50 MHz
Modeline "3440x1440_60.00"  419.50  3440 3696 4064 4688  1440 1443 1453 1493 -hsync +vsync
```

```
xrandr --newmode "3440x1440_60.00"  419.50  3440 3696 4064 4688  1440 1443 1453 1493 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-1 "3440x1440_60.00"
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode "3440x1440_60.00"
```

But it didn't worked! What i got instead was this error:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadName (named color or font does not exist)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  16 (RRCreateMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  33
  Current serial number in output stream:  33
xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed
```

I then saw some people suggesting to manually add the --crtc 0 flag ( then i tried to change it to 1 & 2 ) but i got the same error

I then tried to switch to Wayland and followed a guide that said to add it as a custom kernel property so i did the following:

```
robert@robert-Vostro-3400:~$ for p in /sys/class/drm/*/status; do con=${p%/status}; echo -n "${con#*/card?-}: "; cat $p; done
eDP-1: connected
HDMI-A-1: connected
```

Edited this line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash video=HDMI-A-1:3440x1440@60"
```

and ran a

```
sudo update-grub
```

and reboot but this didn't worked either ( and yes on windows it was working just fine, same monitor same HDMI cable same port )

What is " interesting " is that when i was looking into the logs to see if there was some more meaningful error i saw X logging these available modes so i assume it's recognizing that these are all legit resolutions

```
dic 06 14:22:13 robert-Vostro-3400 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[15342]: (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
dic 06 14:22:13 robert-Vostro-3400 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[15342]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "3440x1440"x0.0  543.50  3440 3488 3552 3600  1440 1443 1453 1510 -hsync +vsync (151.0 kHz eP)
dic 06 14:22:13 robert-Vostro-3400 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[15342]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "3440x1440"x0.0  319.75  3440 3488 3520 3600  1440 1443 1453 1481 +hsync -vsync (88.8 kHz e)
dic 06 14:22:13 robert-Vostro-3400 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[15342]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "2560x1440"x0.0  241.50  2560 2608 2640 2720  1440 1443 1448 1481 +hsync -vsync (88.8 kHz e)
dic 06 14:22:13 robert-Vostro-3400 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[15342]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "3440x1440"x0.0  265.25  3440 3488 3520 3600  1440 1443 1453 1474 +hsync -vsync (73.7 kHz e)
dic 06 14:22:13 robert-Vostro-3400 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[15342]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "2580x1080"x0.0  182.46  2580 2628 2660 2740  1080 1097 1105 1111 +hsync -vsync (66.6 kHz e)
dic 06 14:22:13 robert-Vostro-3400 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[15342]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  148.50  1920 2448 2492 2640  1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (56.2 kHz e)
dic 06 14:22:13 robert-Vostro-3400 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[15342]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  
...etc etc etc
```

Any tips ? I'm kinda running out of ideas :(

### Edit 1

```
xrandr --verbose
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 6912 x 2160, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected 3072x1728+3840+0 (0x45) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 174mm
    Identifier: 0x42
    Timestamp:  121361
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Gamma:      0.53:1.0:1.7
    Brightness: 0.72
    Clones:    
    CRTC:       1
    CRTCs:      1 0 2 3
    Transform:  1.599991 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.599991 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: bilinear
    _MUTTER_PRESENTATION_OUTPUT: 0 
    EDID: 
        00ffffffffffff0038702b0000000000
        011c0104951f117802b370985d598e28
        1c505400000001010101010101010101
        0101010101011a3680a070381f403020
        350035ae1000001a522b80a070381f40
        3020350035ae1000001a000000fe0056
        5030383880313430324c303100000000
        0000412196001000000a010a20200007
    vrr_capable: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
    Colorspace: Default 
        supported: Default, BT709_YCC, XVYCC_601, XVYCC_709, SYCC_601, opYCC_601, opRGB, BT2020_CYCC, BT2020_RGB, BT2020_YCC, DCI-P3_RGB_D65, RGB_WIDE_FIXED, RGB_WIDE_FLOAT, BT601_YCC
    max bpc: 12 
        range: (6, 12)
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    panel orientation: Normal 
        supported: Normal, Upside Down, Left Side Up, Right Side Up
    scaling mode: Full aspect 
        supported: Full, Center, Full aspect
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
    CONNECTOR_ID: 308 
        supported: 308
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
  1920x1080 (0x45) 138.500MHz +HSync -VSync *current +preferred
        h: width  1920 start 1968 end 2000 total 2080 skew    0 clock  66.59KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1111           clock  59.93Hz
  1920x1080 (0x46) 110.900MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1920 start 1968 end 2000 total 2080 skew    0 clock  53.32KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1111           clock  47.99Hz
  1680x1050 (0x47) 119.100MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1680 start 1728 end 1760 total 1840 skew    0 clock  64.73KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1059 total 1080           clock  59.93Hz
  1400x1050 (0x48) 121.915MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1400 start 1488 end 1640 total 1880 skew    0 clock  64.85KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1052 end 1064 total 1082           clock  59.93Hz
  1600x900 (0x49) 97.677MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1600 start 1648 end 1680 total 1760 skew    0 clock  55.50KHz
        v: height  900 start  903 end  908 total  926           clock  59.93Hz
  1280x1024 (0x4a) 107.845MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock  63.89KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock  59.93Hz
  1400x900 (0x4b) 86.578MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1400 start 1448 end 1480 total 1560 skew    0 clock  55.50KHz
        v: height  900 start  903 end  913 total  926           clock  59.93Hz
  1280x960 (0x4c) 107.880MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1376 end 1488 total 1800 skew    0 clock  59.93KHz
        v: height  960 start  961 end  964 total 1000           clock  59.93Hz
  1440x810 (0x4d) 151.771MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  1440 start 1464 end 1480 total 1520 skew    0 clock  99.85KHz
        v: height  810 start  811 end  814 total  833           clock  59.93Hz
  1368x768 (0x4e) 72.347MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1368 start 1416 end 1448 total 1528 skew    0 clock  47.35KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  781 total  790           clock  59.93Hz
  1280x800 (0x4f) 71.028MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1360 total 1440 skew    0 clock  49.33KHz
        v: height  800 start  803 end  809 total  823           clock  59.93Hz
  1280x720 (0x50) 63.951MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1360 total 1440 skew    0 clock  44.41KHz
        v: height  720 start  723 end  728 total  741           clock  59.93Hz
  1024x768 (0x51) 64.924MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock  48.31KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  59.93Hz
  960x720 (0x52) 116.871MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   960 start 1024 end 1128 total 1300 skew    0 clock  89.90KHz
        v: height  720 start  720 end  722 total  750           clock  59.93Hz
  928x696 (0x53) 108.937MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   928 start  976 end 1088 total 1264 skew    0 clock  86.18KHz
        v: height  696 start  696 end  698 total  719           clock  59.93Hz
  896x672 (0x54) 102.262MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   896 start  960 end 1060 total 1224 skew    0 clock  83.55KHz
        v: height  672 start  672 end  674 total  697           clock  59.93Hz
  1024x576 (0x55) 42.080MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1072 end 1104 total 1184 skew    0 clock  35.54KHz
        v: height  576 start  579 end  584 total  593           clock  59.93Hz
  960x600 (0x56) 76.916MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   960 start  984 end 1000 total 1040 skew    0 clock  73.96KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  604 total  617           clock  59.93Hz
  960x540 (0x57) 37.322MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width   960 start 1008 end 1040 total 1120 skew    0 clock  33.32KHz
        v: height  540 start  543 end  548 total  556           clock  59.93Hz
  800x600 (0x58) 38.357MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  824 end  896 total 1024 skew    0 clock  37.46KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  603 total  625           clock  59.93Hz
  840x525 (0x59) 59.550MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   840 start  864 end  880 total  920 skew    0 clock  64.73KHz
        v: height  525 start  526 end  529 total  540           clock  59.93Hz
  864x486 (0x5a) 30.686MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width   864 start  912 end  944 total 1024 skew    0 clock  29.97KHz
        v: height  486 start  489 end  494 total  500           clock  59.93Hz
  700x525 (0x5b) 60.957MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   700 start  744 end  820 total  940 skew    0 clock  64.85KHz
        v: height  525 start  526 end  532 total  541           clock  59.93Hz
  800x450 (0x5c) 48.838MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   800 start  824 end  840 total  880 skew    0 clock  55.50KHz
        v: height  450 start  451 end  454 total  463           clock  59.93Hz
  640x512 (0x5d) 53.922MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   640 start  664 end  720 total  844 skew    0 clock  63.89KHz
        v: height  512 start  512 end  514 total  533           clock  59.93Hz
  700x450 (0x5e) 43.289MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   700 start  724 end  740 total  780 skew    0 clock  55.50KHz
        v: height  450 start  451 end  456 total  463           clock  59.93Hz
  640x480 (0x5f) 25.172MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.46KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  59.93Hz
  720x405 (0x60) 22.098MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width   720 start  768 end  800 total  880 skew    0 clock  25.11KHz
        v: height  405 start  408 end  413 total  419           clock  59.93Hz
  684x384 (0x61) 36.173MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   684 start  708 end  724 total  764 skew    0 clock  47.35KHz
        v: height  384 start  385 end  390 total  395           clock  59.93Hz
  640x360 (0x62) 17.932MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  688 end  720 total  800 skew    0 clock  22.41KHz
        v: height  360 start  363 end  368 total  374           clock  59.93Hz
  512x384 (0x63) 32.462MHz -HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   512 start  524 end  592 total  672 skew    0 clock  48.31KHz
        v: height  384 start  385 end  388 total  403           clock  59.93Hz
  512x288 (0x64) 21.004MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   512 start  536 end  552 total  592 skew    0 clock  35.48KHz
        v: height  288 start  289 end  292 total  296           clock  59.93Hz
  480x270 (0x65) 18.661MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   480 start  504 end  520 total  560 skew    0 clock  33.32KHz
        v: height  270 start  271 end  274 total  278           clock  59.93Hz
  400x300 (0x66) 19.148MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   400 start  412 end  448 total  512 skew    0 clock  37.40KHz
        v: height  300 start  300 end  301 total  312           clock  59.93Hz
  432x243 (0x67) 15.343MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   432 start  456 end  472 total  512 skew    0 clock  29.97KHz
        v: height  243 start  244 end  247 total  250           clock  59.93Hz
  320x240 (0x68) 12.562MHz -HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   320 start  328 end  376 total  400 skew    0 clock  31.41KHz
        v: height  240 start  245 end  246 total  262           clock  59.93Hz
  360x202 (0x69) 11.023MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   360 start  384 end  400 total  440 skew    0 clock  25.05KHz
        v: height  202 start  204 end  206 total  209           clock  59.93Hz
  320x180 (0x6a)  8.966MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   320 start  344 end  360 total  400 skew    0 clock  22.41KHz
        v: height  180 start  181 end  184 total  187           clock  59.93Hz
HDMI-1 connected primary 3840x2160+0+0 (0x6b) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 797mm x 334mm
    Identifier: 0x43
    Timestamp:  121361
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Gamma:      0.53:1.0:1.7
    Brightness: 0.72
    Clones:    
    CRTC:       0
    CRTCs:      1 0 2 3
    Transform:  2.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 2.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: bilinear
    _MUTTER_PRESENTATION_OUTPUT: 0 
    EDID: 
        00ffffffffffff0022f6256a22f680c0
        08200103805021780a54b1ac5047a426
        115054bfcf0081408180714f81c0b300
        d1c0010101014ed470a0d0a046503040
        3a001d4e3100001ce77c70a0d0a02950
        30203a001d4e3100001a000000fd0030
        901ea03c010a202020202020000000fc
        005a51452d4341410a202020202001c7
        020348f14b1f9014010304121305025a
        2309070783010000e200d567030c0010
        00384067d85dc4017880006d1a000002
        013090e60000000000e305c081e30f00
        00e606050166661c565e00a0a0a02950
        302035001d4e3100001a9d6770a0d0a0
        225030203a001d4e3100001a464714a0
        a0381f40302018041d4e3100001a001d
    HDCP Content Type: HDCP Type0 
        supported: HDCP Type0, HDCP Type1
    Content Protection: Undesired 
        supported: Undesired, Desired, Enabled
    max bpc: 12 
        range: (8, 12)
    content type: No Data 
        supported: No Data, Graphics, Photo, Cinema, Game
    Colorspace: Default 
        supported: Default, SMPTE_170M_YCC, BT709_YCC, XVYCC_601, XVYCC_709, SYCC_601, opYCC_601, opRGB, BT2020_CYCC, BT2020_RGB, BT2020_YCC, DCI-P3_RGB_D65, DCI-P3_RGB_Theater
    aspect ratio: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, 4:3, 16:9
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
    CONNECTOR_ID: 317 
        supported: 317
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
  1920x1080 (0x6b) 148.500MHz -HSync -VSync *current
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  67.50KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  60.00Hz
  1920x1080 (0x6c) 148.500MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  67.50KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  60.00Hz
  1920x1080 (0x6d) 148.500MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2448 end 2492 total 2640 skew    0 clock  56.25KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  50.00Hz
  1920x1080 (0x6e) 148.352MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  67.43KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  59.94Hz
  1680x1050 (0x6f) 119.000MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1680 start 1728 end 1760 total 1840 skew    0 clock  64.67KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1059 total 1080           clock  59.88Hz
  1280x1024 (0x70) 135.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1296 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock  79.98KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock  75.02Hz
  1280x1024 (0x71) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock  63.98KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock  60.02Hz
  1280x960 (0x72) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1376 end 1488 total 1800 skew    0 clock  60.00KHz
        v: height  960 start  961 end  964 total 1000           clock  60.00Hz
  1152x864 (0x73) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1152 start 1216 end 1344 total 1600 skew    0 clock  67.50KHz
        v: height  864 start  865 end  868 total  900           clock  75.00Hz
  1280x720 (0x74) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1390 end 1430 total 1650 skew    0 clock  45.00KHz
        v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock  60.00Hz
  1280x720 (0x75) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1720 end 1760 total 1980 skew    0 clock  37.50KHz
        v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock  50.00Hz
  1280x720 (0x76) 74.176MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1390 end 1430 total 1650 skew    0 clock  44.96KHz
        v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock  59.94Hz
  1024x768 (0x77) 78.750MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1040 end 1136 total 1312 skew    0 clock  60.02KHz
        v: height  768 start  769 end  772 total  800           clock  75.03Hz
  1024x768 (0x78) 75.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1328 skew    0 clock  56.48KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  70.07Hz
  1024x768 (0x79) 65.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock  48.36KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  60.00Hz
  800x600 (0x7a) 50.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  856 end  976 total 1040 skew    0 clock  48.08KHz
        v: height  600 start  637 end  643 total  666           clock  72.19Hz
  800x600 (0x7b) 49.500MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  816 end  896 total 1056 skew    0 clock  46.88KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  604 total  625           clock  75.00Hz
  800x600 (0x7c) 40.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock  37.88KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock  60.32Hz
  800x600 (0x7d) 36.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  824 end  896 total 1024 skew    0 clock  35.16KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  603 total  625           clock  56.25Hz
  720x576 (0x7e) 27.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   720 start  732 end  796 total  864 skew    0 clock  31.25KHz
        v: height  576 start  581 end  586 total  625           clock  50.00Hz
  720x480 (0x7f) 27.027MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   720 start  736 end  798 total  858 skew    0 clock  31.50KHz
        v: height  480 start  489 end  495 total  525           clock  60.00Hz
  720x480 (0x80) 27.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   720 start  736 end  798 total  858 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  480 start  489 end  495 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
  640x480 (0x81) 31.500MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  720 total  840 skew    0 clock  37.50KHz
        v: height  480 start  481 end  484 total  500           clock  75.00Hz
  640x480 (0x82) 31.500MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  664 end  704 total  832 skew    0 clock  37.86KHz
        v: height  480 start  489 end  492 total  520           clock  72.81Hz
  640x480 (0x83) 30.240MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  704 end  768 total  864 skew    0 clock  35.00KHz
        v: height  480 start  483 end  486 total  525           clock  66.67Hz
  640x480 (0x84) 25.200MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.50KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  60.00Hz
  640x480 (0x85) 25.175MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
  720x400 (0x86) 28.320MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   720 start  738 end  846 total  900 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  400 start  412 end  414 total  449           clock  70.08Hz
```

new attempt after installing higher-dpi fonts

```
robert@robert-Vostro-3400:~$ cvt -r 3440 1440 60 
# 3440x1440 59.97 Hz (CVT) hsync: 88.82 kHz; pclk: 319.75 MHz
Modeline "3440x1440R"  319.75  3440 3488 3520 3600  1440 1443 1453 1481 +hsync -vsync
robert@robert-Vostro-3400:~$ xrandr --newmode "mymode"  319.75  3440 3488 3520 3600  1440 1443 1453 1481 +hsync -vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-1 "mymode"
robert@robert-Vostro-3400:~$ xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode "mymode" --verbose
screen 0: 6912x2880 1625x677 mm 108.00dpi
crtc 0:       mymode  59.97 +0+0 "HDMI-1"
xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed
crtc 0: disable
crtc 1: disable
crtc 2: disable
crtc 3: disable
screen 0: revert
crtc 0: revert
crtc 1: revert
crtc 2: revert
crtc 3: revert
```

HOWEVER if i look into the journalctl logs and search for Printing DDC gathered Modelines i find these:

```
Dec 07 18:08:32 robert-Vostro-3400 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2121]: (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
Dec 07 18:08:32 robert-Vostro-3400 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2121]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "3440x1440"x0.0  543.50  3440 3488 3552 3600  1440 1443 1453 1510 -hsync +vsync (151.0 >
Dec 07 18:08:32 robert-Vostro-3400 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2121]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "3440x1440"x0.0  319.75  3440 3488 3520 3600  1440 1443 1453 1481 +hsync -vsync (88.8 k>
Dec 07 18:08:32 robert-Vostro-3400 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2121]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "2560x1440"x0.0  241.50  2560 2608 2640 2720  1440 1443 1448 1481 +hsync -vsync (88.8 k>
Dec 07 18:08:32 robert-Vostro-3400 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2121]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "3440x1440"x0.0  265.25  3440 3488 3520 3600  1440 1443 1453 1474 +hsync -vsync (73.7 k>
Dec 07 18:08:32 robert-Vostro-3400 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2121]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "2580x1080"x0.0  182.46  2580 2628 2660 2740  1080 1097 1105 1111 +hsync -vsync (66.6 k>
Dec 07 18:08:32 robert-Vostro-3400 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2121]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  148.50  1920 2448 2492 2640  1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (56.2 k>
Dec 07 18:08:32 robert-Vostro-3400 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2121]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  148.50  1920 2008 2052 2200  1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (67.5 k>
Dec 07 18:08:32 robert-Vostro-3400 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2121]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080i"x0.0   74.25  1920 2448 2492 2640  1080 1084 1094 1125 interlace +hsync +vs>
Dec 07 18:08:32 robert-Vostro-3400 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2121]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
Dec 07 18:08:32 robert-Vostro-3400 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2121]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "720x480"x0.0   27.00  720 736 798 858  480 489 495 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
Dec 07 18:08:32 robert-Vostro-3400 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2121]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1280x720"x0.0   74.25  1280 1390 1430 1650  720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync (45.0 kHz e)
Dec 07 18:08:32 robert-Vostro-3400 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2121]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "720x576"x0.0   27.00  720 732 796 864  576 581 586 625 -hsync -vsync (31.2 kHz e)
Dec 07 18:08:32 robert-Vostro-3400 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2121]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1280x720"x0.0   74.25  1280 1720 1760 1980  720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync (37.5 kHz e)
Dec 07 18:08:32 robert-Vostro-3400 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2121]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080i"x0.0   74.25  1920 2008 2052 2200  1080 1084 1094 1125 interlace +hsync +vs>
Dec 07 18:08:32 robert-Vostro-3400 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2121]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz e)
Dec 07 18:08:32 robert-Vostro-3400 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2121]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   36.00  800 824 896 1024  600 601 603 625 +hsync +vsync (35.2 kHz e)
Dec 07 18:08:32 robert-Vostro-3400 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2121]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   31.50  640 656 720 840  480 481 484 500 -hsync -vsync (37.5 kHz e)
Dec 07 18:08:32 robert-Vostro-3400 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2121]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   31.50  640 664 704 832  480 489 492 520 -hsync -vsync (37.9 kHz e)
Dec 07 18:08:32 robert-Vostro-3400 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2121]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   30.24  640 704 768 864  480 483 486 525 -hsync -vsync (35.0 kHz e)
Dec 07 18:08:32 robert-Vostro-3400 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2121]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "720x400"x0.0   28.32  720 738 846 900  400 412 414 449 -hsync +vsync (31.5 kHz e)
Dec 07 18:08:32 robert-Vostro-3400 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2121]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  135.00  1280 1296 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (80.0 k>
Dec 07 18:08:32 robert-Vostro-3400 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2121]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   78.75  1024 1040 1136 1312  768 769 772 800 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
Dec 07 18:08:32 robert-Vostro-3400 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2121]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   75.00  1024 1048 1184 1328  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (56.5 kHz e)
Dec 07 18:08:32 robert-Vostro-3400 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2121]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz e)
Dec 07 18:08:32 robert-Vostro-3400 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2121]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   49.50  800 816 896 1056  600 601 604 625 +hsync +vsync (46.9 kHz e)
Dec 07 18:08:32 robert-Vostro-3400 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2121]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   50.00  800 856 976 1040  600 637 643 666 +hsync +vsync (48.1 kHz e)
Dec 07 18:08:32 robert-Vostro-3400 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2121]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1280x960"x0.0  108.00  1280 1376 1488 1800  960 961 964 1000 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
Dec 07 18:08:32 robert-Vostro-3400 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2121]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 k>
Dec 07 18:08:32 robert-Vostro-3400 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2121]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1152x864"x0.0  108.00  1152 1216 1344 1600  864 865 868 900 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz e)
Dec 07 18:08:32 robert-Vostro-3400 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2121]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1680x1050"x0.0  119.00  1680 1728 1760 1840  1050 1053 1059 1080 +hsync -vsync (64.7 k>
Dec 07 18:08:32 robert-Vostro-3400 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2121]: (--) modeset(0): HDMI max TMDS frequency 320000KHz
```

Comment: I have no experience of Wayland but in the X11 world try the following or some combination of the following and report back: (1) When you do the newmode/addmode etc don't use the name generated by CVT, call it "mymode" or whatever, something short/simple without underscore. (2) Try reduced blanking mode `cvt -r 3440 1440 60` to generate the modeline. (3) Try a lesser refresh rate e.g. `cvt 3440 1440 30`

Comment: Hello @codlord i've already tried those as well but i end up with the same error ( with both the -r flag or the lesser refresh rate ) 

xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode  mm --verbose
screen 0: 3840x1766 1015x467 mm  96.00dpi
crtc 0:           mm  29.95 +0+326 "HDMI-1"
xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed
crtc 0: disable
crtc 1: disable
crtc 2: disable
crtc 3: disable
screen 0: revert
crtc 0: revert
crtc 1: revert
crtc 2: revert
crtc 3: revert


where "mm" is the new mode i created at 3440 1440 30

Comment: Possibly your laptop only supports up to 1920x1080? See: https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000126548/resolution-on-external-monitor-limited-to-1920-x-1080-using-hdmi

Comment: Hmm nope on windows it was working just fine with the same cable on the same port ( the integrated gpu should support up to 4k )

Comment: Can you add the output of `xrandr --verbose` to your original question? Sort of just guessing at stuff now, I thought the error about named font was a red herring but maybe try installing the high-dpi fonts? `sudo apt-get install xfonts-100dpi xfonts-75dpi`

Comment: Yeah don't worry i've tried everything i could guessing it's all we have left!! Btw i have updated the original question with the new infos ( no success it seems :/ )